# Lightweight tool to create video montages?

Tags: video, video-editing

Do you know a tool to create video collages? I made the one below with After Effects, but I'm looking for something lightweight.

https://twitter.com/Szili/status/839510854496370688

Answer (score 1):

You can do lots of effects like that with [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) which has the following prerequisites:

- [Python](https://www.python.org/) *Obviously*
- Numpy, imageio, Decorator, tqdm and FFMPEG *(All automatically installed)*
- [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) *Optional*
- [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) - For previews
- PIL or Pillow *Advanced Use*
- Scipy *Advanced Use*
- Scikit Image *Advanced Use*
- OpenCV >= 2.4.6 *Advanced Use*

You can inset one or more videos on top of another as shown [here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/examples/ukulele_concerto.html).
You can join movies together on the screen in an [uneven manner](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/examples/example_with_sound.html) using masks.
Even place different movies in various [shapes](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/examples/compo_from_image.html)

[image: Complex Composting]

You can even use it, with [video grep](https://github.com/antiboredom/videogrep/), to select clips based on the subtitles and paste them together.

All of the software mentioned above is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform *Win/OS-X/Linux*
- Small and compact, (by modern standards).

  - Download of the Python installer is ~30 MB,
  - FFMPEG < 50 MB,
  - OpenCV (if required) is quite large at 120 MB,
  - SciPy+Numpy is about 62 MB,
  - imagemagick about 20 MB and those are the biggest downloads.